# Typo3 page media (images) missing after transfer to new host

Tags: php, image, typo3

I've transferred a Typo3 installation to the new host, steps performed are:

- Copy files and exported database from old host
- uploading files and creating database at new host
- changing config to match new hosts database settings
- upgrading typo3 installation to latest version (at that time, current version is 6.1.3)
- configured ImageMagick because this was missing at the new server

At this point, i noticed pages in the frontend where missing images. The website uses the imagecycle plugin.

Checks I have performed:

- folder permissions
- uploads/fileadmin folders checked if they contained the missing images (yes, they did)
- cleared db temp files as well folder temp directories

Still missing the images on the frontend as well in the backend under the media tab of the page settings.

What else can I try?

**Update**
After some help we discovered there was a huge change in the file storage of Typo3. I've upgraded the installation from 4.5 to 6.1.3 which probably caused the loss of the image-links. Images are moved from the /uploads dir to the /fileadmin/_migrated dir. Is there any way to relink these images, or will i have to add all images to the pages manually again?

**Update 2** Unfortunately I didn't find any solution and ended up re-linking the images to the pages 1 by 1.

Comment: Which TYPO3 Version are you using?

Comment: Hi Merec, it's running on Typo3 version 6.1.3

Comment: Have you tried to reinitialized the file index? Check out the scheduler and run the File Index Task. Maybe there are some wrong references.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Merec, am I right this is the one you mean?

File Abstraction Layer: Indexing job (scheduler)

Just ran this job but unfortunately the images are still not displayed.

Comment: Did you run the upgrade wizards in the install tool? They usually take care of these images, at least they did it for me the last time I did such an update.

Comment: @Jost, yep I have done that..

Comment: Are all the images missing or just some from the imagecycle plugin? In the latter case, is the extension up to date?

Comment: @Urs I think it didn't have anything to do with the plugin, it were the images in the media tab at a page.. Also the extension is up to date. I ended up to attach the images again for every page, since they still could be found in the _migrated/pics folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can clear the Typo3 cache in the install tool. It's also safe to truncate the cache tables with phpmyadmin.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately this didn't change anything.